# How to set a custom identifier for events in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have following code in my program when I tried to run the program I'm getting  "Cannot assign to 'eventIdentifier' in 'event'".

```
       var event = EKEvent(eventStore: inEventStore)
        event.calendar = inCalendar   
        event.title = title
        event.notes = notes
        event.startDate = startDate
        event.endDate = endDate
        event.eventIdentifier = identifier
```

Comment: what is wrong with the system's event identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because evenIdentifier is a readonly property, here is snippet from Apple's documentation:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, nonnull) NSString *eventIdentifier
```

I know its very late to answer this, hope answer will help other devs.